# Bluebird array of promises .all or .settle looping over Loopback model methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs, bluebird

I am attempting to loop over a bunch of records, perform a lookup for each, then perform some permutations on the inner lookup (0->1, 0->2, 0->3, 1->2, 1->3, 2->3) and write the permutations to a table. I've got a working synchronous script but I can't figure out how best to use bluebird and the loopback persisted model methods.

If I run it asynchronously with my script, it takes too long to process, and sometimes I run out of memory--and the whole thing is a memory hog to begin with: **nothing is written to the DB until all permutations have been looped over**. This might be because of PersistedModel so it may be useful to go straight to node-mysql with promisifyAll().

Eventually would love to parallelize this to write all the permutations per trip at the same time.

First I wrapped the PersistedModel.create() and .find() calls in promises:

```
function createRoute(newRoute) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    Route.create(newRoute, function(err, route) {
      if (!err) {
        resolve(route);
      } else {
        reject(err);
      }
    });

  });

}

function getHopsFor(trip) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    Schedule.find({
      where: {
        name: trip.name,
        tripCode: trip.tripCode,
        companyCode: trip.companyCode
      },
      order: 'eta ASC',
    }, function(err, hops) {
      if(err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      resolve(hops);
    });
  });
}
```

Yes, this is an anti-pattern but I can't use .promisifyAll() on the library (as a whole or explicitly on .create()) since it's a bit incompatible. I think native promises are on the way but not quite ready yet (correct me if I'm wrong, so I can *use the promise I already have* ;)).

My main question is how would I loop over the above .find() and .create() promises and save an array of promises, so I could then use Promise.settle() to only exit when all new routes have been written to the DB. And chain the whole thing with .then()s properly.

In conjunction with the create a single sailing wrapper and a few other promise wrappers, the main execution loop is something like this:

```
getTrips().then(function(trips){

  for(t = 0; t < trips.length; t++) {

    getHopsFor(trips[t]).then(function(hops) {

      getRoutesFor(hops).then(function(routes) {

        for(r = 0; r < routes.length; r++) {
          routes.push((createRoute(route));

        }

        Promise.settle(routes).then(function(results){
          console.log("finished trip " + t)
        });

      });

    });

  }

});
```

My initial script used nested callbacks and was sort of manageable but wanted to try a Bluebird version to wrap my head around Promises.all() and .settle(). Need to use less memory and get the execution time down.

Comment: I don't really get what is not working here, maybe it is that `getHopsFor` gets fired for all trips in parallel. Can you show us your working synchronous, and the nested callbacks asynchronous, scripts so that we can show you how to replicate their behaviour with promises?

Answer (score 0):

ES5 + Promise

```
function createRoutesForTrips () {
  return getTrips().then(function(trips) {
    return Promise.all(trips.map(function(trip) {
      return getHopsFor(trip).then(function(hops) {
        return getRoutesFor(hops);
      }).then(function(routes) {
        return Promise.all(routes.map(function(route) {
          return createRoute(route);
        }));
      });
    }));
  });
}
```

ES6 fat arrow

```
var createRoutesForTrips = () =>
  getTrips().then((trips) =>
    Promise.all(trips.map((trip) =>
      getHopsFor(trip).then((hops) =>
        getRoutesFor(hops)
      ).then((routes) =>
        Promise.all(routes.map((route) =>
          createRoute(route)
        ))
      )
    ))
  )
```

ES7 async function

```
async function createRoutesForTrips () {
  let trips = await getTrips()
  for (let trip of trips) {
    let hops = await getHopsFor(trip)
    let routes = await getRoutesFor(hops)
    for (let route of routes) {
      await createRoute(route)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You did notice that your ES7 version is doing something different than the first two?

Comment: You should use for await  when looping on async scope.